# jQuery: using a variable as a selector

Tags: jquery, variables, jquery-selectors

I'm having problems using a variable as the selector for a paragraph on which I want to take action.
Specifically I have several title elements and the same number of paragraphs. The desired result is that if I click on Title1 then I take an action on paragraph1. I made a simple case for development purposes whereby if I click on a title then the text of the corresponding paragraph changes color.
If I hard code the solution it works but passing in a variable as the selector fails.

The jQuery is as follows:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
       $(this).click(function(){

        var target=(event.target.id);// Get the id of the title on which we clicked. We will extract the number from this and use it to create a new id for the section we want to open.
        alert(target);// checking that we are getting the right value.
        var openaddress=target.replace(/click/gi, "section");//create the new id for the section we want to open.
        alert('"#'+openaddress+'"');//Confirm that the correct ID has been created
        $('"#'+openaddress+'"').css( "color", "green" );//get the id of the click element and set it as a variable.
        //$("#section1").css( "color", "green" );//Test to confirm that hard coded selector functions correctly.

            return false;// Suppress the action on the anchor link.
            });


    });
```

The alert returns the following variable
[image: alert returned showing the value of the variable]
which appears to be correct and matches the hard coded version.
I've omitted the html since it works in the hard coded version I assume there is no problem on that side.

I'd appreciate any guidance on what I'm doing wrong and how to correct it.

Thanks

Comment: Try omitting the second quotes around `"#section1"` so the string actually passed to jQuery will be `#section1` as desired.  If that makes sense. Try just passing `'#' + openaddress`.  Note that your code passes in `"#section1"` and your test uses `#section1`.

Comment: The `"#foo"` in `$("#foo")` is called a **string literal** and it produces the string *value* `#foo`. String literals are denoted by two quotation marks (either double or single quotes). This is similar for other values: `[...]` denote an array, `/.../` a regex literal, `{...}` an object, etc. Those symbols tell the parser how to interpret the character sequence. They are **not** part of the value themselves! So, jQuery expects `#foo` as a selector, but you are including the quotation marks in the value and pass `'#foo'`, which is incorrect.

Comment: @FelixKling: Thanks for the help. I wasn't clear on the string literal and the value used by jQuery. I needed the explanation hence the 'duplicate' question for me wasn't helpful (but only because of my ignorance.)

Answer (score 220, accepted):

You're thinking too complicated. It's actually just `$('#'+openaddress)`.

Comment: Alternatively you can use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) (`\``). In your case `$(\`${openaddress}\`)`