# Pass string to jQuery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have several classes with the names like so:

- .x-string
- .y-string
- .z-string

A dynamic part and a constant one. I have made an array containing the dynamic parts (x, y, z).

I want to loop through the array, take each name, concatenate "-string" to the end of it, and pass it as a class to be selected in jQuery.

Sort of like:

```
$(classList).each(function () {
    let newClass = '.' + this + '-string'
    $('.this-string')...
}
```

Is this possible and how would I go about it? Cheers.

Comment: `$(newClass)...` or `$("." + this + "-string")...` there will be numerous duplicates in SO if you'd like to search - but this might be hard to find unless you know the specific things to look for

Comment: assuming `classlist` is an array: `classList.forEach(function (className) { $('.' + className + '-string')... }` should work.

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17097947/jquery-using-a-variable-as-a-selector and its duplicate(s)

Comment: You have two parts to your question - using a variable as a selector and iterating over an array - you are using the wrong `.each` - see http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to loop through the array,

jQuery works with arrays differently than it works with it's on jQuery object wrapper.  So to loop through an array you'd use [jQuery.each() or $.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/).

```
var myArray = ['x', 'y', 'z'];
$.each(myArray, function(idxArray, valArray) {
  // code
});
```

> concatenate "-string" to the end of it, and pass it as a class to be selected in jQuery

Now we can use the jQuery selector with [.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/) to find matching elements

```
var myArray = ['x', 'y', 'z'];
$.each(myArray, function(idxArray, valArray) {

  var selector = "." + valArray = "-string";
  $(selector).each(function(idxElement, valElement) {
    var $this = $(valElement);
    // or
    var $this = $(this);

    $this.fadeOut();

  });

});
```

It's important to note that the second `.each()` should only be used if you have specific logic to run after an item is found.  If the code is the same for every element, then each is not needed:

```
var selector = "." + valArray = "-string";
// fadeOut all matching elements
$(selector).fadeOut();
```

It's also important to note that if the logic is as simple as your example, you should not need to loop at all.  You can create a comma delimited string containing all the selectors.

```js
var myArray = ["a","b","c","d"];

var selector = myArray
  .map(s => "." + s + "-string")
  .join();

  $(selector).css("color", "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Black</div>
<div class="a-string">Red</div>
<div>Black</div>
<div class="b-string">Red</div>
<div>Black</div>
<div class="c-string">Red</div>
<div>Black</div>
<div class="d-string">Red</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

### JQuery

[`$.each`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) is used for iteration of the array. Which takes two arguments `[index, element]`.

The `element` is the element of an array. Don't use `this` because it's not recommended!

```js
$(classList).each((idx, elem) => {
  $('.'+elem+'-string')
});
```

### Native

To use the native method we'll use the [`[].forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) or [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) iteration.

**NOTE**: `for...of` method has only support from ES6.

```js
// for...of loop
for(i of elem)
  $(`.${elem}-string`)

// forEach loop
elem.forEach(function(elem) {
  $('.'+elem+'-string')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Some general issues with your usage of `.each`.  Try:

```
$(classList).each(function(idx, cls) {
    let newClass = '.' + cls + '-string';
    $(newClass) ...
});
```