# How to find Elements which have been set with dynamic ids

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

I would appreciate some help with the following.

I have had to set the `id` for each  my countdown timer dynamically for each row  of my cards so that each timer has a unique id.  I set the IDs through a `$each` loop and that works fine and tested.

I am trying to find it so I can output the values of the countdown timer.

Before I did it with php. Using the SQL result row id was the id.

```
 $("#timer<?php echo $id; ?>").val(days + "d " + hours + "h "+ minutes + "m " + seconds + "s" ).css("color", "black");
```

The timer counter display would look like this.

```
<input id="timer<?php echo $id; ?>"  class="timer" type="text" name="" value="" disabled>
```

The timer counter display looks like this as THEtimer id now set via a `$each` loop dynamically.

The array ids are used for the timer counter id. eg. "timer3"

```
<input id="timer"  class="timer" type="text" name="" value="" disabled>
```

I have left the variable like this in a class so you see it working `$('.timer')`

```
$('.timer').val(days + "d " + hours + "h "+ minutes + "m " + seconds + "s" ).css("color", "black");
```

**My Problem**
How do I fill in the elements `$(xxxx)..` something like this `$("#",timer+id)`  The `#` needs to be there.

**The snippet**

In the snippet, I have left the element as `$('.timer')` so you see it working.

After page load press the start timer button to start the counter timer. It will alert the Id of the counter before starting the counter.

**End game**

I want each row to have its own unique countdown timer

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  // simulates jason data result from Ajax
  var data = [

{ "id":"1", "name": "Mike" ,"surname": "Rynes" ,"expiredate": "2021/02/25 23:25:00"},
{ "id":"2", "name": "James" ,"surname": "Bond" ,"expiredate": "2021/02/26 23:25:00"},
{ "id":"3", "name": "Harry" ,"surname": "Potter" ,"expiredate": "2021/02/27 23:25:00"},
  
    ];
  
     $.each(data, function( i, person ) {
    
    
   var personDetailCloned = $('.card').first().clone().show();
      
   personDetailCloned.find('.id').text(person.id);
   personDetailCloned.find('.name').text(person.name);
   personDetailCloned.find('.surname').text(person.surname);
   personDetailCloned.find('.expiredate').val(person.expiredate);
      
      //Generate a random number to be used for timer id
       var timerid = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
               personDetailCloned.find('.timer').attr("id","timer"+person.id);
       
      $('.card-container').append(personDetailCloned);
    
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="album py-1">
  <div class="container bg-light">
    <div class="row py-2">
      <div class="col-md-3 card-container" >
        <div class="card mb-3 shadow-sm"  style="display:none;">
          <div class="hover-container">
         </div>
          <div class="card-body CarDetail">
           <p class="card-text font-weight-bold">ID:
                 <span class="id"></span>
            </p>
            <p class="card-text font-weight-bold">Name:
                   <span class="name"></span>
            </p>
            <p class="card-text font-weight-bold">Surname:  
                <span class=" surname"></span>
            </p>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
              <p class="font-weight-bold ">Registration: 
                 <span class="font-weight-plain"></span>
                <span class="registration"></span> <span>Expires:
                
        <input  type="text" class="timer"  id="timer"  value=""> </span> 

         <input type="text" class="expiredate" value="">
              </p>  
              
                    
<script>

$(document).ready(function () {
$(document).on('click', '.card .starttimer-btn', function(event){

var expiredate = $(this).closest('.card').find('.expiredate').val();
var id = $(this).closest('.card').find('.timer').attr("id");

 
alert(id);


//alert(expiredate);

var countDownDate = new Date(expiredate).getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get today's date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();

  // Find the distance between now and the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  //Output the result in an element with id="demo"
 $('.timer').val(days + "d " + hours + "h "+ minutes + "m " + seconds + "s" ).css("color", "black");


  // If the count down is finished, write some text
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }
}, 1000);

});
});

</script>

</div>
 <p><button class="starttimer-btn" >Start Timer</button> </p>
 </div>
 </div>
</div>   
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Any help and advice to get me there is very appreciated thank you!

Comment: It looks like all that question boils down to:  *how do I use a variable in a selector eg `$("#",timer+id)`* - if that's the case, you're very close:  `$("#timer" + id)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery: using a variable as a selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17097947/jquery-using-a-variable-as-a-selector)

Comment: @ freedomn-m    Thanks  i have tied what you suggested but unfortunately it has not worked. The button start timer button does nothing now.  I spent a lot of time and effort contructing this post as some say not enough info.  Please run a code snippet so I see a working version of that you are suggesting.  I did hope it would be that simple :-)

Comment: The alert I setup in the Snippet proves timer ID is working.

Comment: Look at what the alert is telling you and at what I've suggested.  The alert states "timer1" but I've suggested `"timer"+id` which would give you "timertimer1" - shouldn't have been too hard for you to realise that you already had the "timer" prefix so you don't need that in the text.  Giving `$("#"+id).val(...`.   Added  a snippet with an  answer so you don't have to come back with "didn't work" :)

Comment: @freedomn-m     Thanks for your help   :-)   Some times things get so complicated that I begin to miss the simple things.

Comment: You do have a bit of an XY problem.  Your real problem is "How can I reference this input?"  which you've attempted to solve by adding a dynamic ID - but then you've asked "How can I access the dynamic ID" - the answer is: **don't use a dynamic ID**.  *They are not your friend*.   Updated the answer to show you how to remove the need for the dynamic ID.

Comment: @freedomn-m, thanks for you advice and the ammendments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the `id` retrieved from `.attr("id")` already contains the full `id`, you can use:

```
$("#" + id).val(...
```

to add the "id selector" (#) in front of your id.

Everything else is unchanged.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // simulates jason data result from Ajax
  var data = [

    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Mike",
      "surname": "Rynes",
      "expiredate": "2021/02/25 23:25:00"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "James",
      "surname": "Bond",
      "expiredate": "2021/02/26 23:25:00"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "name": "Harry",
      "surname": "Potter",
      "expiredate": "2021/02/27 23:25:00"
    },

  ];

  $.each(data, function(i, person) {


    var personDetailCloned = $('.card').first().clone().show();

    personDetailCloned.find('.id').text(person.id);
    personDetailCloned.find('.name').text(person.name);
    personDetailCloned.find('.surname').text(person.surname);
    personDetailCloned.find('.expiredate').val(person.expiredate);

    //Generate a random number to be used for timer id
    var timerid = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    personDetailCloned.find('.timer').attr("id", "timer" + person.id);

    $('.card-container').append(personDetailCloned);

  });
});


$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.card .starttimer-btn', function(event) {

    var expiredate = $(this).closest('.card').find('.expiredate').val();
    var id = $(this).closest('.card').find('.timer').attr("id");


    alert(id);


    //alert(expiredate);

    var countDownDate = new Date(expiredate).getTime();

    // Update the count down every 1 second
    var x = setInterval(function() {

      // Get today's date and time
      var now = new Date().getTime();

      // Find the distance between now and the count down date
      var distance = countDownDate - now;

      // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
      var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
      var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
      var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
      var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

      //Output the result in an element with id="demo"
      console.log(id, $('#' + id).length);
      
      $('#' + id).val(days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s").css("color", "black");


      // If the count down is finished, write some text
      if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
      }
    }, 1000);

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="album py-1">
  <div class="container bg-light">
    <div class="row py-2">
      <div class="col-md-3 card-container">
        <div class="card mb-3 shadow-sm" style="display:none;">
          <div class="hover-container">
          </div>
          <div class="card-body CarDetail">
            <p class="card-text font-weight-bold">ID:
              <span class="id"></span>
            </p>
            <p class="card-text font-weight-bold">Name:
              <span class="name"></span>
            </p>
            <p class="card-text font-weight-bold">Surname:
              <span class=" surname"></span>
            </p>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
              <p class="font-weight-bold ">Registration:
                <span class="font-weight-plain"></span>
                <span class="registration"></span>
                <span>Expires:
                    <input  type="text" class="timer"  id="timer"  value=""> 
                </span>
                <input type="text" class="expiredate" value="">
              </p>
            </div>
            <p><button class="starttimer-btn">Start Timer</button> </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

---

While the above answers your question, it would be remiss of me not to remind you that dynamic IDs are not-your-friend(tm).

You rarely need a dynamic ID (if a framework adds them, which they do in some cases then you can ignore them).

With two minor changes to your code, you can get rid of the dynamic IDs:

Instead of

```
var id = ...
```

Store the element itself:

```
var timerOutput = $(this).closest('.card').find('.timer');
```

then you can reference it directly:

```
timerOutput.val(...
```

Updated snippet (just 2 lines changed (and a console.log removed))

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // simulates jason data result from Ajax
  var data = [

    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Mike",
      "surname": "Rynes",
      "expiredate": "2021/02/25 23:25:00"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "James",
      "surname": "Bond",
      "expiredate": "2021/02/26 23:25:00"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "name": "Harry",
      "surname": "Potter",
      "expiredate": "2021/02/27 23:25:00"
    },

  ];

  $.each(data, function(i, person) {


    var personDetailCloned = $('.card').first().clone().show();

    personDetailCloned.find('.id').text(person.id);
    personDetailCloned.find('.name').text(person.name);
    personDetailCloned.find('.surname').text(person.surname);
    personDetailCloned.find('.expiredate').val(person.expiredate);

    //Generate a random number to be used for timer id
    var timerid = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    personDetailCloned.find('.timer').attr("id", "timer" + person.id);

    $('.card-container').append(personDetailCloned);

  });
});


$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.card .starttimer-btn', function(event) {

    var expiredate = $(this).closest('.card').find('.expiredate').val();
    
    // get the element (jquery obj)
    var timerOutput = $(this).closest('.card').find('.timer');
    var countDownDate = new Date(expiredate).getTime();

    // Update the count down every 1 second
    var x = setInterval(function() {

      // Get today's date and time
      var now = new Date().getTime();

      // Find the distance between now and the count down date
      var distance = countDownDate - now;

      // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
      var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
      var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
      var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
      var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

      timerOutput.val(days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s").css("color", "black");


      // If the count down is finished, write some text
      if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
      }
    }, 1000);

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="album py-1">
  <div class="container bg-light">
    <div class="row py-2">
      <div class="col-md-3 card-container">
        <div class="card mb-3 shadow-sm" style="display:none;">
          <div class="hover-container">
          </div>
          <div class="card-body CarDetail">
            <p class="card-text font-weight-bold">ID:
              <span class="id"></span>
            </p>
            <p class="card-text font-weight-bold">Name:
              <span class="name"></span>
            </p>
            <p class="card-text font-weight-bold">Surname:
              <span class=" surname"></span>
            </p>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
              <p class="font-weight-bold ">Registration:
                <span class="font-weight-plain"></span>
                <span class="registration"></span>
                <span>Expires:
                    <input  type="text" class="timer"  id="timer"  value=""> 
                </span>
                <input type="text" class="expiredate" value="">
              </p>
            </div>
            <p><button class="starttimer-btn">Start Timer</button> </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```