# jQuery combine variable with pseudo class

Tags: jquery

How can I combine a jQuery variable with a pseudo class - for example:

```
listItem = $('li');

listItem.addClass();      // Works on all li's
$(listItem).addClass();   // Works on all li's

$('li:first-child').addClass(); // Works ( on first li )

$(listItem + ':first-child').addClass(); // Doesn't Work..
```

Similarly I'd like to be able to do this with data attributes, for example to use some variant of:

```
listItem[data-index="1"]
```

instead of:

```
    $('li[data-index="1"]')
```

I've found a couple questions which deal with variables after such as $('#element-' + variable'), which don't help in this case.

[jQuery: using a variable as a selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17097947/jquery-using-a-variable-as-a-selector),

[jQuery selectors with variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893436/jquery-selectors-with-variables)

And also tried 'template literals' ( ${id} ) to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using the `.children()`, like so:

```
listItem.children().eq(0).addClass();
```

But you are not trying to select the child elements, you want to first element in the Group.

```
listItem.eq(0).addClass();
```

That should work as you expect.

```js
$(function() {
  var listItems = $("li");
  listItems.eq(0).addClass("first");
});
```

```css
.first {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: There is an alias for that `.first()` https://api.jquery.com/first/

Comment: Thanks both for contributing - I was hoping there was a more direct way of doing it but I guess that answers my question in that these approaches are required - no real bother at the end of the day :)

Comment: @CultDigital I hope it helps. If it does, I hope you will upvote the answer. If it does answer your question, I hope you will mark it as the answer.